# Real self-hosted password manager

Tags: password-manager

I am looking for a password manager that doesn't have any intermediary entities between me and my vault. It has to have desktop versions for Windows and Linux (at least debian/ubuntu) and browser extensions for chrome and furryfox. The vault would be either in a form of docker container or DB server that i can launch in the cloud. The most important part is that it doesn't store master password hash anywhere except my vault. Is there something you can recommend?

Answer (score 2):

What about [Buttercup](https://buttercup.pw/)?

As far as I know, it meets most of your requirements:

- Desktop version on Linux, MacOS and Windows
- Browser extensions to store passwords
- Stores master password in vault db file

While it does not use a docker container or DB server, you can easily get similar functionality by storing the vault db file in a cloud drive of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

[Bitwarden](https://bitwarden.com/help/install-on-premise-linux/) seems like a good option.

It uses docker, and can even be air-gapped if you need to be absolutely certain it doesn't talk back to the developers.

You can use it on Linux, MacOS, Windows, Android, iOS, and basically all the popular browsers.